# Passing values from a route using query string to the view template

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3

There are certain `$scope`'s values which contains string values in it and declared inside one controller. These `$scope` values are fetched from a view template and stored inside it.

I want to pass these `$scope`'s values to the same view template but on different div of the template.

How is it possible to pass it using query string using angular routing.

Remember:

1. view Template
2. controllers

Routes the same template with different urls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I prefer to pass using ngHref:

```
<a ng-href="#/myRoute/{{myId}}">link1</a>
```

or, of course, you can do the same thing using $window.location:

```
$window.location = '#/myRoute/' + $scope.myId;
```